# Git with VS 2013 throws error on sync

Tags: git, version-control, visual-studio-2013

Error is as follows:

An error occurred. Detailed message: An error was raised by libgit2. Category = Odb (NotFound).
Object not found - failed to find pack entry (c4efb72101798a007ab82b1c86a65fada23b4982)

When I execute a pull I get the same message. When I go to the command line I am able to pull, but then one of my submodules has a merge conflict. The merge conflict is on the submodule folder itself and despite having configured a diff tool VS, when asked to compare files, throws a git error of "Failed to start the configured tool"

Has anyone else encountered this behavior? Does anyone know how or what might be the root cause? Any resolutions out there? Thanks.

Comment: What is the output of `git fsck`?

Comment: When you say "submodule" are you referring to git submodule or to a module in your code?

Comment: A git sub-module; but I think I figured out the issue: VS 2013 does not seem to gracefully hand projects with sub-modules included via the few git commands exposed via the GUI. To resolve the issue I executed git commands against the sub-modules (pull, commit, etc.) and then the referencing project. That seemed to do the trick. I will post a more detailed description of the resolution shortly.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a bug in VS 2013.

Just install VS 2013 Update 2 and it gets resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2013, Update 3 will do this if you're trying to clone something that is itself a clone. So, if you created the git repository you're cloning with something like this:

```
git clone --bare --shared c:\myproject \\path\to\shared\myproject
```

Visual Studio will give this error if others try to clone `\\path\to\shared\myproject`. If, however, you `init` a repository and then push to it, as in

```
git init --bare --shared \\path\to\shared\myproject
git remote add shared \\path\to\shared\myproject
git push shared master
```

then VS2013 Update 3 will be able to clone.

Comment: I got this error with Update 4. Created a project locally, then created a team project at VS Online, cloned it and copied in the content from the local project and tried to sync. Sync gave the error message, but push worked.